# Gmapping to slow?

Tags: slam, navigation, turtlebot, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all, just  had a quick question. I'm doing some mapping with turtlebot however not all is going well. I am working with  the mapping tutorial and i am finding that rviz isnt updating fast enough. It really only updates ever 30sec-1min which is way to slow to capture any data. I have found that the rviz process begins take 100% of the cpu speed of my turtlebot or workstation depending on which one it is run on.

Is there anything I could be doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51649/gmapping-to-slow?/) by [Shleaky](https://answers.ros.org/users/3763/shleaky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You want to make sure nothing extra is running.  So get it started and then turn off rviz and anything else unnecessary.  Viewing the system can take as much or more resources than the execution on computationally limited machines like the TurtleBot.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0